# C# logic (solution needed in coding)

Tags: c#

I want to use as loop like : Example
i putted in textbox 123 and 300 in my formula.

**1/2*(300+123/300) = 150.205 >> answer**

i want to loop this Example i got answer 150.205 next formula should be look like this

**1/2*(150.205+123/150.205)  = 75.512**

the answer of this equation i want to put in next formula by loop.

i have written code but i don't know how to use it via loop

## My code.

```
double value = (0.5 * (300 + 123 / 300));
```

=======================================

For End loop

When condition match like this 
1/2*(11.091+123/11.091) = 11.091
Meaning Answer and input where i m putting 300  will be same i want to break loop

```
**Example** I want to do this without using square root function in c# 
    like simple if i want a root of 9 it will be 3 so it will be like this .
    i choosen 1 Because 9 is one value so i choosen 1
    1/2*(1+9/1) = 5.000
    1/2*(5+9/5) = 3.400
    1/2*(3.4+9/3.4)  =   3.024 
    1/2*(3.024+9/3.024) = 3.000
    1/2*(3+9/3) = 3.000 
    see you will get same value in one point  always
```

Comment: when do you want to stop looping ?

Comment: C'mon Jonny, you can try harder than that before asking for advice.

Comment: When condition match like this 
=1/2*(11.091+123/11.091)
Meaning Answer and input where i m putting 300  will be same i want to break loop

Comment: And how do you know you will get that condition?

Comment: "Teach me programming" - thanks, but no thanks.

Comment: Because its a way to check square root without using square root function its old way its working i checked in Ms Excel before code.

Comment: your code is not matching your description. you are saying you want `0.5*(a+b/a)` and your code says `0.5*(a + b / b)` which essantially says `0.5*(a+1)`. So which one is correct?

Comment: i rectified that  sorry typing mistake

Comment: so do you want to stop when you get a value of precisely 11.091 or close to?

Comment: Yes Sir Same or below then that  i want to close the loop anything. but it will be same it will not go below

Comment: What if you enter values other than 300 & 123 - then you will want to stop looping at a different value - how will you know that?

Comment: like simple if i want a root of 9 it will be 3 so it will be like this .
i choosen 1 Because 9 is one value so i choosen 1
1/2*(1+9/1) = 5.000
 1/2*(5+9/5) = 3.400
 1/2*(3.4+9/3.4)  =   3.024 
1/2*(3.024+9/3.024) = 3.000
1/2*(3+9/3) = 3.000 
see you will get same value in point always

Comment: But that means you must know the answer you want before you start looping, so you can stop when you get there. Dmitry has given a good answer below - I was trying to get you to think about the solution & work something like that out yourself.

Comment: Sir even you dont know the answer in the last when condition match 
answer and input like this  300 matches answer 300 so its correct :)
like above example i dont know 9 root answer is 3 but when i apply my formula it proves 3 = 3 in last just see

Comment: So that would be your stopping condition - the point I was trying to get you to work out yourself - you keep looping until the answer doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only *tricky thing* here is a comparison with *tolerance*, since because of *round up errors* you can well *never* meet

```
  answer == value
```

condition. The implementation could be

```
  double answer = 300.0;
  double tolerance = 1e-10;

  while (true) {
    // based on previous answer we compute next one
    double value = 0.5 * (answer + 123.0 / answer);

    //TODO: you can print out steps here, if you want something like this
    //Console.WriteLine(value);  

    // check convergence with tolerance 
    if (Math.Abs(answer - value) <= tolerance) {
      answer = value;

      break;
    }

    // next answer (value) becomes the previous one (answer)
    answer = value;
  }

  // 11.0905365064094
  Console.Write(answer);
```

The actual answer (prove it) is just a *square root*:

```
  // 11.09053650640941716205160010261...
  Console.Write(Math.Sqrt(123));
```

Real life implementation (if my boss wants me to implement it):

```
public static double NewtonEstimation(Func<double, double> function, 
                                      double tolerance = 1e-10, 
                                      double guess = 1.0) {
  if (null == function)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("function");
  else if (tolerance < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("tolerance", "tolerance must not be negative");

  while (true) {
    double value = function(guess);

    if (Math.Abs(value - guess) <= tolerance)
      return value;

    guess = value;
  }
}

...
// 11.0905365064094
Console.Write(NewtonEstimation(x => 0.5 * (x + 123 / x)));
```

Comment: @Jonny: I see, square root, *Newton method*; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: My question its also called a rough estimation method which i am asking :)
But if you like 
can you solve in programming C# newton method i will appreciate if you can solve it

Comment: Great Sir Dmitry Bychenko its working

Comment: As doubles have limited precision then you will always get to the point where "answer == value" - the round-up errors will only affect the accuracy of the result.

Comment: @PaulF: *No*, just put `tolerance = 0;` and thus `Math.Abs(answer - value) <= 0` which equals to `answer == value` and you'll see the bitter and ugly reality; you can even put, say, `tolerance = 1e-100` (*greater* than 0) and have an *infinite loop*

Comment: I just used a "value == guess" check & a selection of numbers that I knew had no precise square root value - the loop always exited. Using a tolerance will just exit sooner.

Comment: @PaulF: it can vary from FPU to FPU, Intel FPU (former x87 co-processor) can use 80-bit (so called `long double`) for floating point values and then round them up to 64-bit `double`; this feature can result in `(answer == value)`; other CPU's like Spark use 64-bit FPU   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Sir @Dmitry one request if you can modify your function to show me steps like this not direct answer but i what i want is
 { 1/2*(1+9/1) = 5.000
    1/2*(5+9/5) = 3.400
    1/2*(3.4+9/3.4)  =   3.024 
    1/2*(3.024+9/3.024) = 3.000
    1/2*(3+9/3) = 3.000 }
is it possible ?

Comment: I know all of the theory & understand why you suggested using a tolerance which may be needed in many calculations - but this method loops around getting more & more accurate until it goes beyond the precision (15/16 digits) of a double value - then you will get to the situation where (answer == value).